# Insert delay between keypress events and set display time

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, delay

I'm trying to insert delays in a sequence of stimuli that are presented on the keypress event.
The code below shows how I'd tried to insert a 1000ms delay between stimuli (i.e. after the key was pressed, it should take 1000ms before the next stimulus appears). Yet there seems to be no delay. Where am I wrong (is it better to do this with setTimeout)?

And: how could I set the maximum 'display-time' of each stimulus to, say, 2000ms, so that it automatically presents another stimulus even if no key is pressed?

```
var stim = [ 
        {name:"WORD1", path:".../pic1.jpg"},
        {name:"WORD2", path:".../pic2.jpg"},
        {name:"WORD3", path:".../pic3.jpg"},
            ]


$(function(){
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is('input, textarea')) {
        return;
    };
    if (e.which === 97 || e.which === 108) {
        if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
            var new_word = stim[Math.floor((Math.random()*stim.length)+1)].name;
            $("#abc").delay(1000).text(new_word);
        } else {
            var new_img =  stim[Math.floor((Math.random()*stim.length)+1)].path;
            $("#abc").delay(1000).empty();
            var prox_img = $('<img id="abcimg" height="300px" width="300px">');
            prox_img.attr('src', new_img);
            prox_img.appendTo('#abc');
        }
    };
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for delay: https://api.jquery.com/delay/

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects.

You should be using setTimeout for this since it also allows you to cancel it. That is really important for your need to have a maximum timeout.

So, first I would break your function up. You could have a function that handles the displaying, which will get called when timeout occurs or when a key is pressed.

```
$(function(){
  var to = 0; //this is used to clear your timeout when the user clicks a button
  function showNext() {
    if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
      var new_word = stim[Math.floor((Math.random()*stim.length)+1)].name;
      $("#abc").delay(1000).text(new_word);
    } else {
      var new_img =  stim[Math.floor((Math.random()*stim.length)+1)].path;
      $("#abc").delay(1000).empty();
      var prox_img = $('<img id="abcimg" height="300px" width="300px">');
      prox_img.attr('src', new_img);
      prox_img.appendTo('#abc');
    }
  to = setTimeout(function(){showNext()}, 2000);
}
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is('input, textarea')) {
        return;
    };
    clearTimeout(to);
    if (e.which === 97 || e.which === 108) {
      setTimeout(function(){showNext();}, 1000);  
    }
});
});
```